# Obtener cada numero de cada día de la semana actual

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Quisiera mostrar al usuario un calendario pequeño, que visualice la semana actual donde estamos ubicados.
Así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mas o menos así lo quiero en un array:
Lun:19,mar:20,mier:21,jue:22,vier:23,sab:24,Dom:25.

Solo quisiera obtener el numero del día y el día de la semana actual y no tengo ni la remota idea de hacerlo alguien podría ayudarme?.

Answer (score 5):

Pues puedes obtenerlo con la funcion `getDay()`.

**Ejecuta el siguiente ejemplo:**

```js
var meses = new Array ("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
        var dias = new Array('domingo','lunes','martes','miercoles','juev es','viernes','sabado')
        var f=new Date();
        document.write("Hoy es:"+dias[f.getDay()]+" "+f.getDate() + " de " + meses[f.getMonth()] + " de " + f.getFullYear()+" y ");
        
        f.setDate(f.getDate() - f.getDay());//seteamos al primer dia de la semana
        
        document.write("El primer dia de la semana es:"+dias[f.getDay()]+" "+f.getDate() + " de " + meses[f.getMonth()] + " de " + f.getFullYear());
```

y si deseas seguir dia a dia solo haces `f.setDate(f.getDate() +1);`

Comment: Eso mismo pero para todos los días de la semana actual de lunes a domingo tienes alguna idea para eso?

Comment: @DiegoLopez, Pues si te funciono, puedes marcarlo como respuesta para asi ayudar a otras personas que tambien buscas esta solucion.

Comment: no entiendo ahi esta la respuesta

Comment: Me traes el día de hoy y el numero del día, listo hay esta bien pero necesito que lo haga con todos los días de la semana a la vez que me de un array con el numero del día lunes de esta semana y asi sucesivamente hasta el domingo .

Comment: @DiegoLopez, ya edite mi respuesta, haber si esa si te sirve

Comment: Genial, sencillo y practico :)

Answer (score 1):

Una vez has obtenido el Lunes de la Semana actual sólo tienes que iterar 7 días y mapear tus valores.

```js
// Obtener Lunes de la Semana actual
const date = (() => {
  const now = new Date();
  return new Date(now.setDate(now.getDate() - now.getDay() - -1));
})();
// Recorrer la semana
const week = Array(7).fill(date).map((date, i) => {
  if (i !== 0) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  }
  const name = date.toLocaleDateString('es-ES', { weekday: 'short' });
  return { 
    [name[0].toUpperCase()]: date.getDate()
  };
});

console.log(week);
```

Comment: Esto esta mas que excelente! aunque tengo una pregunta, ya hoy es lunes pero sigue mostrando la semana pasada ¿porque?

Comment: Se se calculaba correctamente el día de la semana en otras casuísticas, ahora ya está.

Answer (score -1):

Creo que lo que quieres es algo así:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#date").datepicker({
        //In Datepicker set the Calendar display start with Monday
        firstDay: 1,
        //Before Populating the Calendar set the Enabled & Disabled Dates using beforeShowDay(Date) function
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            //var monday = new Date("June 1, 2013 00:00:00");
            //Get today's date
            var monday = new Date();
            //Set the time of today's date to 00:00:00 
            monday.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            /*
            Below Line sets the Date to Monday (Start of that Week)
            (monday.getDay() || 7) returns the value of getDay() 
            ie., [ 1 - Mon, 2 - Tue, 3 - Wed, 4 - Thu, 5 - Fri, 6 - Sat ]  
            except for Sunday where it returns 7. 
            The return value is used to calculate the Date of that Week's Monday
            */
            monday.setDate(monday.getDate() + 1 - (monday.getDay() || 7));
            //Set the Date to Monday
            var sunday = new Date(monday);
            //Now add 6 to Monday to get the Date of Sunday (End of that Week)
            sunday.setDate(monday.getDate() + 6);
            //Now return the enabled and disabled dates to datepicker            
            
            return [(date >= monday && date <= sunday), ''];
        }
    });
    //Set the date format to dd/mm/yy ie., 30/10/1989
    $("#date").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-unselectable{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
  integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <div id="date"></div>
```

He cogido [esta](http://blog.geekzgrand.com/blog/tag/enable-only-current-week-in-jquery-datepciker/) versión modificada y he ocultado las filas deshabilitadas, así sólo tienes la semana actual del mes. Habría que hacer más pruebas pero creo que es un buen punto de partida.